# Adding extended JTable to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, imageicon

## **What I want to do:**

I have created a table class that extends the JTable. My aim is to display an image found in the Internet after obtaining input from the user (at the moment I'm just using a hardcoded URL for testing). One column is supposed to be ImageIcon class, the second one is String. When using a Test class, the JTable (not extended) is drawn correctly, hovewer I cannot get the extended one to display at all. I think I'm missing something in the TeamTable class, but I can't figure out what is it, and why does the Test class (located in the end of the post) actually work.

## The main question:

Why can Test.java properly display the JTable with ImageIcon, but my RoundRobin.java + TeamTable.java does not display anything at all?

## The code :

```
public class TeamTable extends JTable{
    public static final String[] columnNames = {"Team Logo", "Team"};
    public static final Object[][] data = new Object[1][2];     // For test purposes set to [1][2], final value [8][2]
    
    public TeamTable(){
        JTable table = new JTable();
        configureTeamTable(table);      // Override the getColumnClass, set the model
    }                                   // Loop through all teams and assing the names and logos
    
    public static void configureTeamTable(JTable table){
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setRowHeight(50);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i ++){   // For test purposes set to 1, final value 8
            ImageIcon currentTeamLogo = new ImageIcon(RoundRobin.getTeam(i).getLogo());
            String currentTeamName = RoundRobin.getTeam(i).getName();
            data[i][0] = currentTeamLogo;
            data[i][1] = currentTeamName;
        }        
    }
}
```

This is the extended JTable class, I'm creating a new JTable, overriding the getColumnClass method and setting both columns using the input gathered from the user in the main class.

```
public class Team {
    private String name;
    private Image logo;
    private ArrayList<String> players;
   
    
    public Team(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Team(){}

    public void searchImg(){
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.wearjersey.com/product_images/uploaded_images/milanlogo.jpg");
            this.logo = ImageIO.read(url);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOe");
        }
    }
        
    public void resizeLogo(){
        Image tempImg = this.getLogo();
        tempImg = tempImg.getScaledInstance(30,30, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        setLogo(tempImg);
    }
} //only GETTERS and SETTERS below, removed to keep the code shorter
```

This is the Team class, at the moment it always searches for the same image, and can resize it to 30x30px size. The main method is below:

```
public class RoundRobin {

    private JFrame frame;
    private static ArrayList<Team> teams;
    private static int teamCounter = 0;
    
    final int HEIGHT = 400; //1024
    final int LENGTH = 600; //1920
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RoundRobin rr = new RoundRobin();
        rr.paintStuff();
        rr.initFirstUI();
    }
    
    
    public void paintStuff() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(LENGTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }                                              // initiates, sets size etc.
    
    public void initFirstUI() {                                                  // creates the first part of the UI, which will later be replaced by group ladder
        teams = new ArrayList();
        frame.add(new JLabel("Teams"), "wrap, align center");
        JButton addTeamBut = new JButton("Add a team");
        frame.add(addTeamBut);
        addTeamBut.addActionListener(new AddTeamAct());

        refresh();
    }
    
    
    public void refresh() {                                                      // just a revaildate + refresh method
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
    
    public static Team getTeam(int index) {
        return teams.get(index);
    }

    
    class AddTeamAct implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(teamCounter < 1){    // For test purposes set to 1, final value 8
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name of the team");
                
                Team currentTeam = new Team(name);
                currentTeam.searchImg();
                currentTeam.resizeLogo();
   
                teams.add(currentTeam);
                teamCounter++;
            }
            if(teamCounter == 1){   // For test purposes set to 1, final value 8
                TeamTable a = new TeamTable();
                frame.add(a);
            }
            refresh();   
        }
    }
}
```

============== The working Test class, what is the main difference between Test.java and tje TeamTable.java? The Test.java properly displays the JFrame.

```
public class Test {
        private JFrame frame;
        private JTable teamTable;
        private Image logo;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.paintStuff();
        test.addTab();
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void paintStuff(){
        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }        
    
    
    public void addTab(){
        searchImg();
        resizeLogo();
        ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon(logo);
        String[] columnNames = {"Team"};
        Object[][] data = new ImageIcon[8][1];
        data[0][0] = a;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++){
            data[i][0] = a;
        }        
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        
        teamTable = new JTable(model){
            public Class getColumnClass(int column){
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        
        teamTable.setRowHeight(50);
        
        frame.add(teamTable);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
    
    public void searchImg(){
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.wearjersey.com/product_images/uploaded_images/milanlogo.jpg");
            this.logo = ImageIO.read(url);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
    }
        
    public void resizeLogo(){
        Image tempImg = this.logo;
        tempImg = tempImg.getScaledInstance(30,30, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        logo = tempImg;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 4) `TeamTable` both extends `JTable` and has an instance.  That might well be the problem.  Why ***are*** you extending table?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  *"At least your images are available online"*  ..LOL!  I completely failed to notice that.  OP:  Ignore the 3rd point in my comment above, since the code *already does that.*  :P

Answer (score 4):

`TeamTable` both extends `JTable` and has an instance of a `JTable`. That might well be the problem.

As an aside, what the code is trying to achieve seems better implemented in a factory method than by extending `JTable`.